# training vs test data sizes

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, train-test-split

If I have a training set of 10k samples (balanced--two classes) and 20k test samples (imbalanced-- 5% versus 95%), could I compare their ROCs for overfitting/underfitting? I guess not bu I need more clarity. The whole "ROC of training should be higher or equal to the test" only holds if we have more training data compared to test data, right?

-- I know that we prefer to have a bigger training set so it's better to consider some test samples in the training but since the data is imbalanced and I want to have a balanced training data, I had to consider it this way.

Comment: The ROC measures how a classifier performs on a population. Drawing more members from the same population should not affect the ROC beyond statistical fluctuation. If trainROC>testROC only in cases where trainN>testN, it would imply that you could improve the testROC just by increasing testN, eventually getting trainN<testN and trainROC<testROC. But that intuitively makes no sense, a fixed classifier doesn't get any "better" by being applied to more cases.